# wordpress contact widgets provide code to get each field individually

Tags: wordpress

I am a wordpress developer, I need to display phone, fax, address and social menu in the site. sometime all info together and sometimes each field individually at different places. For example I need to show Phone number in header and phone, fax and address in footer and in contact us page. I need to add phone number once and call it individually at multiple places. Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. 
Regards

Comment: I didn't do anything i need the code from scratch. My question is "how can I add contact info fields in back-end of WordPress in single widget and retrieve  single field data to display at multiple areas?". May be it help you understand what I want to code.

Answer (score 0):

Register it like widgets in your functions.php, for example:

```
function my_custom_widget() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Contacts',
        'id'            => 'full_contacts',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );    
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_custom_widget' );
```

Then call it where ever you want in your templates with the widget ID:

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'full_contacts' );
```